# better way to write this code? I am trying to avoid the double return statements

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6

```
 async function formulateResponse({ response, input }) {
  if (response.statusText === 'No Content') {
    return {
      id: input.customerId,
      paymentMethods: [],
    };
  }
  if (response.statusText !== 'OK') throw new Error(await parseResponseErrors(response));
  const data = await response.json();

  return {
    id: input.customerId,
    paymentMethods: data,
  };
}
```

This code works but I don't know how to write it better without breaking the logic. I have tried to use a ternary but of no avail. Can we formulate this better? I am not happy with the double return.

Comment: Perhaps post this to codereview.stackexchange.com? Unfortunately off-topic here, as there's nothing wrong with the code (and any proposed "better" ways would really just be opinions).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't any better

```
async function formulateResponse({ response, input }) {
  const defaultPaymentMethods = [];

  if (['OK', 'No Content'].indexOf(response.statusText === -1) {
     throw new Error(await parseResponseErrors(response)); 
  }

  return  {
    id: input.customerId,
    paymentMethods: response.statusText === 'OK' ?  await response.json().data : [];

};
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can rewrite it to avoid the "double return". However, I'm not certain how much **better** doing so makes it. Use an `else` in your `if`, make `data` have greater scope and a default value. Like,

```
async function formulateResponse({ response, input }) {
  data = [];
  if (response.statusText === 'No Content') {
    // do nothing
  } else if (response.statusText !== 'OK') {
    throw new Error(await parseResponseErrors(response));
  } else {
    data = await response.json();
  }
  return {
    id: input.customerId,
    paymentMethods: data,
  };
}
```